Umbraco conditional logic for dropdowns in forms
Is there a way to add conditional logic on dropdown list options on forms? Depending on another form field I can add conditional logic to either show or hide dropdown field itself but is there a way to apply that logic to dropdown filed options through umbraco. I am using Umbraco 13.
Example: dropdown field 1 has options A, B and C, show dropdown field 2 with options E, F if A is selected in dropdown 1 otherwise show G,H

Hi, did you manage to resolve your issue? Please upvote the helpful answers on this platform and accept them if they help you resolve your issue.

You can create your own custom Umbraco Forms Field Types to achieve that. However, it is generally a good idea to use the built-in Umbraco Forms Conditional Logic on Fields to show or hide other fields, as you have also described in your question. This option will save you from creating your own custom fields.
Details:
Sample custom field type - you can create your own custom dropdown field types(answer types) following this logic.
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Composing;
using Umbraco.Forms.Core.Attributes;
using Umbraco.Forms.Core.Enums;
using Umbraco.Forms.Core.Providers;

namespace MyProject;

public class SliderFieldType : Core.FieldType
{
    public SliderFieldType()
    {
        Id = new Guid("6dff0075-598c-4345-89d7-e0db8684c819");
        Name = "Slider";
        Alias = "slider";
        Description = "Render a UUI Slider field.";
        Icon = "icon-autofill";
        DataType = FieldDataType.String;
        SortOrder = 10;

        FieldTypeViewName = "FieldType.Slider.cshtml";
        EditView = "My.PropertyEditorUi.InputNumber";
        PreviewView = "My.FieldPreview.Slider";
    }

    [Setting("Minimum", Description = "Minimum value", View = "Umb.PropertyEditorUi.Integer", DisplayOrder = 10)]
    public virtual string? Min { get; set; } = "1";

    [Setting("Maximum", Description = "Maximum value", View = "Umb.PropertyEditorUi.Integer", DisplayOrder = 20)]
    public virtual string? Max { get; set; } = "1";

    [Setting("Step", Description = "Step size", View = "Umb.PropertyEditorUi.Integer", DisplayOrder = 30)]
    public virtual string? Step { get; set; } = "1";

    [Setting("Default Value", Description = "Default value", View = "Umb.PropertyEditorUi.Integer", DisplayOrder = 40)]
    public virtual string? DefaultValue { get; set; } = "1";

    [Setting("Hide step values", Description = "Hides the numbers representing the value of each steps. Dots will still be visible", View = "Umb.PropertyEditorUi.Toggle", DisplayOrder = 50)]
    public virtual string? HideStepValues { get; set; }

    [Setting("Background color", Description = "Background color for the input field", View = "My.PropertyEditorUi.InputColor", DisplayOrder = 60)]
    public virtual string? BgColor { get; set; } = "1";
}

Registering the new field as a dependency:
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.Composing;
using Umbraco.Cms.Core.DependencyInjection;
using Umbraco.Forms.Core.Providers;

namespace MyProject;

public class Startup : IComposer
{
    public void Compose(IUmbracoBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.WithCollectionBuilder<FieldCollectionBuilder>()
            .Add<SliderFieldType>();
    }
}

Partial view for the new field type:
@using Umbraco.Forms.Web
@model Umbraco.Forms.Web.Models.FieldViewModel
@{
    var min = Model.GetSettingValue<int>("Min", 1);
    var max = Model.GetSettingValue<int>("Max", 10);
    var step = Model.GetSettingValue<int>("Step", 1);
    var bgColor = Model.GetSettingValue<string>("BgColor", "#fff");
}
<div>This is a custom "slider" field type. We'll just use an input to mock this up.</div>
<input name="@Model.Name"
    style="background-color: @bgColor"
    id="@Model.Id"
    class="text @Html.GetFormFieldClass(Model.FieldTypeName)"
    value="@Model.ValueAsHtmlString"
    type="number"
    min="@min"
    max="@max"
    step="@step" />

